# show that the volume of domain $U$ is $V_{U}=\iiint_{\tilde{U}} \sqrt{g} d u_{1} d u_{2} d u_{3}$ while $g=det(g_{ij})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, volume

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ be an compact domain. Let $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ an coordinate system on $U$ and assume there is a parametrization of $U$ such that $$U: \vec{r}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right)=x_{1}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \hat{i}+x_{2}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \hat{j}+x_{3}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \hat{k}, \quad\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \in \tilde{U}$$

while $\tilde{U}$ is a domain in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and assume $\vec{r}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right)\in C^1$. Lets define the matrix $g_{3x3}$ such that $$g_{i j}=\left\langle\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u_{i}}, \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u_{j}}\right\rangle, \quad 1 \leq i \leq 3,1 \leq j \leq 3$$

Show that $$V_{U}=\iiint_{\tilde{U}} \sqrt{\det(g)} d u_{1} d u_{2} d u_{3}$$

I am not really sure how to approach this problem,
I understand how the matrix $g$ is looks like, and I can see it is a symmetric but what does it represent? I also know there is a relation between determinant to volume but I don't see how those relations can help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has
\begin{equation}
g = J^T J
\end{equation}
where $J = \frac{\partial r}{\partial u}$ is the jacobian matrix of $r$. Hence
\begin{equation}
\det(g) = \det(J)^2 \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \sqrt{\det(g)} = |\det(J)|
\end{equation}
The formula for $V_U$ is simply the change-of-variables formula in the Lebesgue integral in ${\mathbb R}^d$.

Comment: Ok that was smooth solution, just let me sure I understood the idea here, direct calculation of the volume of $U$ is $\iiint dx_1dx_2dx_3$? wich yield the formula I had to show from changing variables?

Comment: Yes, see [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) for example, the paragraph about substitution for multiple variables. In our case, the function $f$ is the constant 1 in the set $U$.